# Extend Global Class with Another Global Class in Coffeescript/Meteor

Tags: oop, inheritance, meteor, coffeescript

I have two global classes, the parent class is:

```
class @Pitcher
    @throw: (ball) -> 'fast'
```

The class to inherit the parent class is (in a separate file):

```
class @Pettitte extends Pitcher
    @playerNumber: -> 5
```

My issue is that the above extends call does not work and I get a compile error: "ReferenceError: Pitcher is not defined"

From what I can tell from the docs I'm doing it right.  What is the way to accomplish this?

If the approach I'm taking is not possible or botching the OOP paradigm, is there a more appropriate way of having one global class inherit or include methods from another global class?

I have read about mixins but that concept doesn't seem to be what I need.

Thanks!

Comment: The code looks fine - it's just a load order issue.

Comment: Okay great, thank you.